# Show/Hide dynamic table columns with Totals

Tags: php, javascript

Good afternoon, in my php/mysql page I have dynamic tables with a row total for each row. I have used a show/hide script to hide certain columns which is great but I would really like the row total to update when column is hidden, iin example below if I hide say Jan it should deduct the value in that column row and update the total column?

Here is the js;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/prototype.js"></script>

<script language="javascript">
function toggleVis(button) { 
  // Toggle column 
  cells = $$('.t'+button.name); 
  cells.invoke(button.checked ? 'show' : 'hide'); 

  // Recaulculate total 
  $$('tr.row').each(function(row) { 
    // Initialise to zero 
    var total = 0; 
    row.down('.total').textContent = total; 

    // Sum all visible cells 
    row.select('td').each(function(cell) { 
      total += cell.visible() ? parseInt(cell.textContent, 10) : 0;
    }); 

    // Write the total in the total cell 
    row.down('.total').textContent = total; 
  }); 
}
</script>
```

And dynamic table + form to hide columns;

```
<form name="tcol" onsubmit="return false">
  Show columns
  <input type=checkbox name="col1" onclick="toggleVis(this.name)" checked> 1
  <input type=checkbox name="col2" onclick="toggleVis(this.name)" checked> 2
  <input type=checkbox name="col3" onclick="toggleVis(this.name)" checked> 3
</form>

<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="tcol1">Adviser</td>
    <td class="tcol2">Jan</td>
    <td class="tcol3">Feb</td>
    <td class="total">Total</td>
  </tr>
  <?php do { ?>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="tcol1"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Adviser']; ?></td>
      <td class="tcol2"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Jan'    ]; ?></td>
      <td class="tcol3"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Feb'    ]; ?></td>
      <td class="total"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Total'  ]; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
</table>
```

Many thanks for looking..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you have to parse your table using Javascript, just after toggling the column.

The easiest way would be to give a class to each rows and each cell. Take care not to use ids for you cells as they won't be unique. Don't use names either, as they are more dedicated to forms and inputs.

```
<tr class="row">
  <td class="tcol1"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Adviser']; ?></td>
  <td class="tcol2"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Jan'    ]; ?></td>
  <td class="tcol3"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Feb'    ]; ?></td>
  <td class="total"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Total'  ]; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Then you would parse your rows and cells like the following ([prototype.js](/questions/tagged/prototype.js) style) :

```
$$('tr.row').each(function(row) {
  // Initialise to zero
  var total = 0;
  row.down('.total').textContent = total;

  // Sum all visible cells
  row.select('td').each(function(cell) {
     total += cell.visible() ? parseInt(cell.textContent) : 0;
  });

  // Write the total in the total cell
  row.down('.total').textContent = total;
});
```

That should work.

You could have a analog code written with other JS frameworks, like [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), needless to say that without any framework it would be quite less trivial.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for your valued input & forgive my lack of knowledge but could I confirm, would I not require my original js, would your example replace that or can I just append it to the end of original js? I tried to test but removing the name & id from td broke the hide option?
Thanks

Comment: nope you have to append the code I provided to the toggling. Be aware that I use prototype.js framework which you have to insert in your page (http://www.prototypejs.org/). You won't regret it. Concerning your toggling, you have to use `getElementsByClassName` instead of `getElementsByName` as I suggested to use class attributes instead of name attributes. Good luck.

Comment: That's great Tom much appreciated for getting me going on teh right tracks, I have called prootype.js and change names/ids to classes as suggested, all columns hide ok but the total still doesn't recalculate unfortunately.

Comment: Hi Tom, I run developer tools in Chrome & all appears to be ok assuming I am running it correctly! I spent most of last night on this just cant see where I am going wrong most probably because I am trying to learn as I go, if there was something I had done wrong it wouldn't jump out at me. Oh well will keep trying, thanks.

Comment: Hmm, looking deeper it outputs this, but clueless what it is actually telling me?

_proto_: Object
type: "unexpected_token"
_proto_: Error
name: "SyntaxError"
_proto_: SetupError.d
name: "Error"

Comment: Hi Tom, the exact code I am using is now posted in original thread at top, I then downloaded prototype.js from your link and linked to in header. Running the page in browser shows now errors, removing the link to prototype.js or removing the suggested additional js code makes no difference, toggle still works but recalc doesn't? I really am at a loss..

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for your patience, I really don't see how I can get this working, I have tried every single variation of placing your recalc code into the togglevis function, all it does for me is set total to 0 & leaves column visible. I am sure you are 100% correct but I just cannot get it working which is a shame after all your help. Can I check you do mean place the recalc code inside the togglevis function and not in the actual toggleform?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14522/discussion-between-tom-desp-and-gary)

Comment: Resolved thanks to Toms patience and knowldege, I have updated the original code at top of thread in case it helps anyone else. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just you try this..

classname is used for hide/show function

```
$('.total').hide();
$('.total').show();
```

or

```
$('.total').toggle();
```

i have checked...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show()
{

$('.total').toggle();


}
</script>
<table>
<tr class="row">
  <td class="tcol1">New</td>
  <td class="tcol2">Jan</td>
  <td class="tcol3">Feb</td>
  <td class="total">Total</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type='button' value='new' id='new' onclick='show()'>
```